# AngularJS - Making Factory and Controllers DRY

Tags: javascript, mvc, angular.js, ajax, http

The following code works, but:

The service makes multiple API calls, the functions are very similar with a lot of code duplication. The same is true for the controllers- very similar code with only slight differences. How could I make this more clean and concise?

```
app.factory('listDataService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    function firstListData() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data.d.results;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }

    function secondListData() {    
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SecondListName')/items",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data.d.results;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }

    return {
        firstListData: firstListData,
        secondListData: secondListData
    }
}]);

app.factory('UtilService', function() {
  return {
    linkLocation: function(url, launchBehavior) { 
      window.open(url, launchBehavior);
    }
  }
});

app.controller('firstController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', 'listDataService', 'UtilService', function ($scope, $http, $window, listDataService, UtilService) {
    listDataService.firstListData().then(function (results) {

        var firstLinksList = $scope.firstLinksList = [];

        if (results.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                var launchBehavior;

                if (results[i].LaunchBehavior == 'New tab') {
                    launchBehavior = '_blank';
                } else {
                    launchBehavior = '_self';
                }

                firstLinksList.push({
                    title: results[i].Title,
                    linkLocationUrl: results[i].LinkLocation.Url,
                    launchBehavior: launchBehavior
                });
            }
        }
    });
    $scope.util = UtilService;
}]);

app.controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', 'listDataService', 'UtilService', function($scope, $http, $window, listDataService, UtilService) {
    listDataService.secondListData().then(function (results) {

        var secondLinksList = $scope.secondLinksList = [];
        if (results.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                var launchBehavior;

                if (results[i].LaunchBehavior == 'New tab') {
                    launchBehavior = '_blank';  
                } else {
                    launchBehavior = '_self'; 
                }

                secondLinksList.push({
                    title: results[i].Title,
                    linkLocationUrl: results[i].LinkLocation.Url,
                    launchBehavior: launchBehavior
                });           
            }
        }
    });
    $scope.util = UtilService;
}]);
```

From searching I think the controllers could use a service? But not sure how to restructure them.

**Edit:**

The HTML is similar to what you used in the [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p4sg-f213), using `ng-repeat` - but with `ng-click` on the list item as well:

I've also added `UtilService` to show how `launchBehavior` is used.

```
<h3>First list</h3>
<ul class="promoted-links">
  <li class="item default promoted-links-item" ng-repeat="link in firstLinksList" ng-click="util.linkLocation(link.linkLocationUrl, link.launchBehavior)" title="{{link.title}}">
    <h6>{{ link.title }}</h6>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3>Second list</h3>
<ul class="promoted-links">
  <li class="item default promoted-links-item" ng-repeat="link in secondLinksList" ng-click="util.linkLocation(link.linkLocationUrl, link.launchBehavior)" title="{{link.title}}">
    <h6>{{ link.title }}</h6>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make the function returned by the factory `listDataService` accept a parameter for the `getbytitle()` value:

```
app.factory('listDataService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return function firstListData(title) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+title+"')/items",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data.d.results;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    };
})
```

Then the callbacks that process the data can be abstracted to a function. The function below replaces the `for` loop with the functional approach of [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
$scope.processResults = function(results) {
    return results.map(function(result) {
        //consideration for launchBehavior?
        // that variable didn't appear to be used...
        return {
            title: result.Title,
            linkLocationUrl: result.LinkLocation.Url
        };
    });
};
```

**Note**: the variable `launchBehavior` didn't appear to be used, so if that is necessary, you will need to update that.

And those can be used to clean up the code to fetch the lists of items:

```
listDataService('ListName').then(function(results) {                    
    $scope.firstLinksList = $scope.processResults(results);
});
listDataService('SecondListName').then(function(results) {                    
    $scope.secondLinksList = $scope.processResults(results);
});
```

[See a demonstration in this PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p4sg-f213) (PHP mostly used to generate lists depending on the URL parameters). **Note**: I only added one single main controller... if you need to have two separate child controllers that we can look at keeping that constraint.

Arrow functions could be used to make those functions even shorter. For example, the `processResults` function can be simplified as below:

```
$scope.processResults = (results) => results.map((result) => {
    return {
        title: result.Title,
        linkLocationUrl: result.LinkLocation.Url
    };
});
```

Comment: This is much better Sam - I like the arrow functions. I updated the question but don't think we'll need to change anything? Thanks for your time and help!